# Cannot find the mistake in a probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients

> We want to distribute $6$ people $ P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4, P_5 $ and $ P_6 $ to $4$ houses $ H_1, H_2, H_3 $ and $ H_4 $. Each person chooses, which house to go. We are searching for the probability that two people are found alone, and the other four in two pairs.

Firstly, I found that there are totally $ 4^6 = 4096 $ contingencies, as all $ 6 $ people are free to choose among  $ 4 $ houses.

Secondly, the number of contingencies that two people are alone, each at a house, and the other four in two pairs, in the two remaining houses, should be :

$$ 4! { 6 \choose 2 \; 2 \; 1 \; 1 } = \cfrac{4!6!}{2!2!1!1!} = 4320  $$

Apparently, something is wrong, as the requested probability will be greater than $ 1 $, as $ 4320 > 4096  $, but I cannot find the mistake.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know where you got the formula from. The correct way to go about this is realizing there are $\frac{12}{2}$ ways you can pick the two houses with a single person in them, and $\frac{6!}{2\cdot 2}$ ways to distribute the people after you've chosen your houses. Their product is smaller than $4096$.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof There are many ways to count things. This is one of the great things about combinatorics!

Comment: Yes, you're right. 'The correct way' was a poor way of phrasing this!

Comment: @Alex Geldhof After picking the two houses, which will have a single person in them, (with 6 ways), shouldn't we consider as well, which person will go to each house, and accordingly which pair will go to each one of the two remaining houses? So shouldn't we multiply 6 with 4 and get $4!$, i.e. take ordering into account, as long as 4096 also takes ordering into account ?

Comment: By calculating $4096$ you do not take ordering into account. I.e. swapping people around in the same house does not yield a different case among the 4096 contingencies.

Comment: @Alex Geldhof Actually I meant the following. I can not understand that with only 6 orderings of specific teams, we can get all the orderings of those specific teams among 4 houses. I think that those are 4! Please see my question on the answer below, I give an example of what I mean.

Comment: If you want to determine teams first and then divide them in houses, the number of different teams is actually $\frac{6!}{2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2}$, as the first pair is not fundamentally different from the second pair and you can therefore swap them around (meaning you have to divide by $2$ once more). The same goes for the two single-member teams.

Comment: @Alex Geldhof Thank you very much, I understood the mistake in my process !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $$\dfrac{4!}{2!2!}$$ ways of ordering the houses so that you have two houses with 2 occupants and two houses with 1 occupant. There are $$\dfrac{6!}{2!2!1!1!}$$ ways of ordering the people into those houses. So, you forgot to divide by 4.

Total:

$$\dfrac{4!6!}{2!2!2!2!1!1!} = 1080$$

Comment: Thank you !! However, the first part of the answer confuses me. For instance, consider the following "teams" of people : (P1P2),(P3P4),P5,P6
. I think that we can we can arrange those four distinct teams in the hotels with 4! ways, rather than 6. What is wrong with my intuition?

Comment: @George, The first part is not counting ways to arrange the *six* people, but ways to select among the *four* houses places to put the people (two houses for pairs, and two for singles).  The second part counts ways to arrange the people into those houses.

Comment: Here is a good example: $$(P_1P_2),(P_3P_4),P_5,P_6 - H_1,H_2,H_3,H_4$$ puts all the same people in the same houses as: $$(P_3P_4),(P_1P_2),P_5,P_6 - H_2,H_1,H_3,H_4$$